# Initialize django Point in queryset annotate

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, postgis

I have a model with `latitude` and `longitude` as `DecimalField`s. I am trying them to `Point` instance of `postgis`and then `transform` to reqd `CRS`. I have written the queryset for that but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.
```

**Queryset**

```
list(Geo.objects.filter()
.values("latitude", "longitude")
.annotate(
    float_long=ExpressionWrapper(F('longitude'), output_field=FloatField()), 
    float_lat=ExpressionWrapper(F('latitude'), output_field=FloatField())
)
.annotate(
    wgs_84=Transform(
        Point(
            F('float_long'), F('float_lat'), srid=srid
        ), 
        4236
    ) 
))
```

Here I am trying to add a value `wgs_84` which will be the transformed value in `wgs84` system.

The error I am getting is related to passing `F('float_long'), F('float_lat')` as params to `Point`.

How can I rectify this error?

**Note: Edited**
Below is the sql query that I wrote to solve my issue:

```
SELECT 
    "id", "altitude", "longitude", "latitude", "<other fields>",
    ST_X(ST_Transform(
        ST_SetSrid(
            ST_MakePoint(
                "longitude", "latitude", "altitude"
            ),
            (select srid from spatial_ref_sys where srid={srid})
        ),
        4326
    )) AS wgs_longitude,
    ST_Y(ST_Transform(
        ST_SetSrid(
            ST_MakePoint(
                "longitude", "latitude", "altitude"
            ),
            (select srid from spatial_ref_sys where srid={srid})
        ),
        4326
    )) AS wgs_latitude 
FROM "My_Table" 
WHERE (<conditions to filter>)
```

Now even though this works, I am looking for a way to get `ST_X`, `ST_Y` values from `transform`ed point to a different CRS.

Also even though I can use `values_list` to get a list of values and then loop through it and get the `transformed point` values for each item, it is slow. So I am looking for a way to get it directly through django orm.

Comment: Why dont you try to first get a clean queryset of the `values_list` of `longitude` and `latitude` and then do whatever you want on that ?

Comment: @haduki Yes I can but looping through it is slow. I have added the extra info in the question now.